# AWS SAM required query string parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-sam, sam

I'm having trouble on specifying `requred query string params` within the `template.yml` file of a SAM project. So far I had no luck on finding a such method and only found that we can access the query string params within a lambda functoin via the `event.queryStringParameters` header.

So should I check if a parameter is required or not at the lambda layer? Or is there a way to do this at the API layer itself. Because I know that in `serverless` framework we can specify if a query string param is required or not as below:

```
functions:
  create:
  handler: posts.create
  events:
    - http:
      path: posts
      method: get
      request:
        parameters:
          querystrings:
            type: true
```

Comment: FYI docs https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api

Answer (score 9):

please find a snippet of a template.yaml below that works for me. Ofc you need to replace the placeholders.

```
MyFunction:
   Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
   Properties:
        CodeUri: <path/to/your/lambda>
        Role: <arn of lambda role>
        Events:
            MyGetEvent:
                Type: Api 
                Properties:
                    Path: <my/api/path>
                    Method: get
                    RestApiId:
                        Ref: MyApi
                    RequestParameters:
                        - method.request.querystring.myqueryparam:
                             Required: true
```

Answer (score 2):

You need not specify *query string parameters* in template.yml.
Invoking API like "http(s)://URL?key=value",m then parse them in lambda via event.queryStringParameters, that's all.

Comment: @Ashan wants to make specific query string parameter mandatory. It is possible to specify it in the template.yaml file. Refer to my example above.